# Add directory contents to the array as an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, fs

[image]

I have a file structure like on a image and code which read folders content like that:

```
var array = []
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/static/katalogi', function (err, files) {
files.forEach(function (fileName) {
    console.log(fileName);
    array.push(fileName)
   });  
});
```

I would like to create structure something like this:

```
var list = {kat1:[files from folder],
kat2:[files from folder],
kat3:[files from folder]}
```

Does someone know how to do that becouse i really don't understand objects in js

Answer (score 0):

You can try following structure to fulfill your need to accessing array data:

```
var list = [
  { kat1: file },
  { kat2: file },
  { kat3: file },
]
```

And to iterate kat (ie kat1, kat2, etc) you can use FormData.

```
new fd = new FormData()
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
   fd.append('kat'+i, file) // output=> {kat1: file}
   list.push(fd)
}
```